# Kivy problems on ubuntu: kivy.app not found, program can't be compiled for android

Tags: android, python, ubuntu, kivy, buildozer

I try to compile an app for android using buildozer, but it quits after opening. So tried to run the program on ubuntu, which I have to use for compiling (buildozer does not work with android on windows). When I run the program by typing python main.py to terminal I recieve this error: No module named kivy.app, when I run it from IDLE it works fine.
What's the reason? And why can't I compile it to android?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: https://kivy.org/docs/guide/android.html#debugging-your-application-on-the-android-platform

Comment: Do you use a virtual environment?

Comment: @inclement thanks a lot